# In R, It comes out as a number that tries to extract characters that match the condition using the ifelse syntax

Tags: r, numbers

There are a total of 100 data from six teams' basketball games. I wrote the R code to see which team wins in each game like this. 
`win = ifelse(dat$away_score > dat$home_score, dat$away, dat$home)`
 However, the name of the basketball team is not output but is output as a number (1,2,3, ..). Of course, 
After naming the basketball teams in alphabetical order, numbers were assigned according to their order. At this time, how do I print the results in the name of the original basketball team rather than numbers?

Comment: You're asking a lot of very general questions, with very little specifics. I suggest you break this multi-question into several, smaller questions. In the first question, post an entire snippet of code (10-20 lines) to paint a better picture of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the columns are `factor`.  We could convert the `factor` to `character` class and then it would work

```
ifelse(dat$away_score > dat$home_score, as.character(dat$away), as.character(dat$home))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what dat looks like, but if I do this:

```
dat <- c()
dat$home <- c("a","b","c") # home team names
dat$away <- c("d","e","f") # away team names
dat$away_score <- c(90,80,70)
dat$home_score <- c(89,81,69)

win = ifelse(dat$away_score > dat$home_score, dat$away, dat$home)
win # print results
```

I get the following showing the "name" of which team won:

```
[1] "d" "b" "f"
```